# Cocoa NSView not filling with color

Tags: cocoa, nsview

What am I doing wrong?

I have an awakeFromNib method in which I am calling a class that is a subview (GameMap). The class exists and I am able to log in the awakeFromNib method as well as log in GameMap's initWithFrame method,  but I cannot get GameMap to draw in the window. Here's my AppController.m file's awakeFromNib method:

-(void) awakeFromNib {

```
    //make new game map
    GameMap* newMap = [[GameMap alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 500.0)];

    [[[NSApp mainWindow] contentView]addSubview:newMap];

    [newMap release];
}
```

and in GameMap.m here's the drawRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {

    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeSourceOver);

}
```

in this same app I am calling two other classes from AppController, all subviews of NSView, MakeCircle and MakeRoom that place either a circle (duh, : D) or a rect with a stroke in the window and they work fine, but they are running off of IBOutlet actions (button clicks). Any help would be appreciated.

*NOTE: I have NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeSourceOver) but this was also failing wiht NSRectFill(rect).

**I can also log the origin.x/size.width, etc. of the passed rect to GameMap from the initWithFrame, so I know it's there.

(I'm away from my computer for a few hours so don't think I'm being rude for not replying, just wanted to get this question out there before I left.)

Comment: Have you checked if `[NSApp mainWindow]` is non-`nil` at the point where your `-awakeFromNib` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Just use NSRectFill(rect); instead of  NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeSourceOver);

Comment: I had tried NSRectFill(rect) before I posted. It was failing on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the view's class to the GameMap class instead of NSView) in the Interface Builder? When you do this, the GameMap's drawRect() should get called automatically.